# Is there a search widget in IP4?

Tags: impresspages

Is there a search widget to hook in our pages?

I search in core files, but I don't see it.
An idea, have you a tip to do it?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use it from a older impresspages version: 
http://www.impresspages.org/docs2/working-with-themes2/layout-1/search/